# An identity of the product of three spinors

Tags: spinors

In Aitchison's "Supersymmetry in particle physics" I found the identity for the product of three spinors:
$$ \lambda(\zeta.\rho) + \zeta (\rho.\lambda) + \rho (\lambda.\zeta)=0 $$

Does anyone have an idea how to prove this identity? or where did it come from?

Comment: This is called the Schouten identity. You can prove it by exanding each spinor in a basis.

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the spinors live in a 2-d vector space we can expand $$\lambda_\alpha = A \xi_\alpha +B \psi_\alpha$$. A and B can be found by taking the inner product with $\xi$ and $\psi$, which when re-inserted into the $\lambda$ expansion gives the desired result